# Wieso ist "nicht müssen" nicht immer gezwungen?

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german

In den meisten Fällen impliziert "müssen" einen Zwang.

> Du musst Kuchen essen.

Wenn man das ganze negiert, erfolgt daraus eine freie Wahl.

> Du musst **keinen** Kuchen essen.

Im englischen und, soweit ich meinen dänischen Kollegen richtig verstanden habe, auch dänischen, ist es immer ein Zwang.

> You must eat Cake.

> You must not eat Cake.

Comment: "Wieso?" bei einer Sprache ist immer eine der schlechtesten Fragemöglichkeiten, weil in den meisten Fällen die Antwort "Ist halt so" lautet.

Comment: Interessant in dem Zusammenhang ist eigentlich nur, daß "du mußt keinen ..." nicht die eigentliche Bedeutung hat, sondern, daß es "du mußt nicht irgendwelchen ..." bedeutet, daß also "keinen" hier die Zusammenziehung von "nicht einen" darstellt.

Comment: @bakunin Um genau zu sein, kann "du mußt keinen" sehr wohl die abweichende Klammerbedeutung (also "musst <nicht einen>", statt "<musst nicht> einen") haben. Dazu braucht es aber Kontext, der die Abweichung vom Standard begründen würde. z.B. "Als Diabetiker musst du eben, wenn du die Wahl hast, auch mal keinen Kuchen essen".

Comment: Sprache ist keine formale Logik, sondern die Logik jeder Sprache funktioniert etwas anders. Da hat es wenig Sinn, nach dem Warum zu fragen und es gibt auch keine "eigentliche" Bedeutung.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Weil die Logik in diesem Fall im Deutschen anders ist als im Englischen.

Im Deutsch ist die Logik:

- "müssen" -> Zwang.
- "nicht müssen" -> Kein Zwang.

Der Unterschied ist, worauf sich das "nicht" bezieht:

- Deutsch: Du (musst nicht) tun.
- Englisch Du musst (nicht tun).

Im Deutschen bezieht sich das "nicht" auf das "müssen", also kein Zwang, aber auch kein Verbot.
Im Englischen bezieht sich das "nicht" auf das "tun", es bleibt also beim Zwang, aber zu einem "nicht tun", also einem Verbot.

Comment: Vielleicht noch als Ergänzung: "Nicht müssen" im Deutschen entspricht eher "don't have to" im Englischen, "You don't have to eat cake". Eine deutsche Entsprechung von "must not" würde eher mit "dürfen" formuliert, "Du darfst keinen Kuchen essen".

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Der Fragesteller hat in seiner Frage durchaus deutlich gemacht, dass er das schon weiß.

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt im Englischen wie im Dänischen das Modalverb *dürfen* nicht. Deshalb müssen beide auf das Modalverb *müssen* oder die Konstruktion *zu haben* zurückgreifen, um *nicht dürfen* auszudrücken.

Das Dänische kennt zwar *turde*, das bedeutet aber eher *sich trauen* als *dürfen*.

Im Deutschen gibt es diese Einschränkung nicht, und daher kann *müssen* im Sinne von *Zwang — kein Zwang* interpretiert werden.

Comment: Hmm. Was ist denn dann *may*? Und *måtte*?

Answer (score 1):

Wenn sich in einem Satz mehrere Verben verbinden, kommt es zu Mehrdeutigkeiten, was den Bezug von Adverbialen angeht.

> obwohl du nicht X versprochen hast

Die Negation *nicht* kann sich auf *versprechen* oder den zu-Infinitiv X beziehen. Wenn X = *zu meckern*, denkt man zuerst an die Negation von X: *obwohl du versprochen hast, nicht zu meckern*. Wenn X = *mitzumachen*, bezieht man die Negation zuerst auf *versprechen*: *obwohl du nicht versprochen hast, mitzumachen*. Je nach Verb und Kontext ist eine Lesart plausibler als die andere.

Auch bei Modalverben gibt es solche Skopusambiguitäten.

> Ich kann auch kein Fleisch essen.

Der Satz wird normalerweise verstanden als *es ist nicht möglich, daß ich Fleisch esse*, mit weitem Skopus der Negation (d.h. das Modalverb wird negiert). Aber in einem geeigneten Kontext ist auch enger Skopus möglich, also Negation des Infinitivs.

> Ich kann auch kein Fleisch essen, wenn dir das lieber ist.
> *Es ist möglich, dass ich kein Fleisch esse*.

Bei *müssen* bzw. *must* ist es normalerweise so: im Englischen hat man engen Skopus (Negation des Infinitivs), im Deutschen weiten Skopus (Negation des Modalverbs).

> You must not call.
> *Es ist nötig, dass du nicht anrufst.*
>
> Du musst nicht anrufen.
> *Es ist nicht nötig, dass du anrufst.*